# SoundCloud: "streamable" inconsistent

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

SoundCloud tracks accessed via the official API have the property `streamable`, which is supposed to indicate whether a track is "streamable via API (boolean)" (https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks).

**Unfortunately, the values of `streamable` are inconsistent with the actual behaviour of the streaming API.**

For example:

https://soundcloud.com/klangkarussell/sonnentanz-v2-neu-gemischt (id: 24412995) has `"streamable": false` and indeed, for a normal app it will not stream.

https://soundcloud.com/cleanbandit/rather-be-feat-jess-glynne (id: 123173738) also has `"streamable": false`, but it will stream.

**Is there an attribute I am currently overlooking that lets developers distinguish between truly streamable tracks? Otherwise, could you please correct the `streamable` property.**

Comment: cleanbandit is a "special user" - you see that coz they have an artist head image (afaik invite only?). i guess they have more options over their tracks. but i am not 100% sure.

Comment: "Rather Be" has been removed, so I lack my test case. Has this been resolved?