# SoundCloud JavaScript SDK: Error Catching

Tags: javascript, soundcloud, soundmanager2

**How do I catch errors occurring during `SC.stream(...)` calls?** Neither

```
try {
    SC.stream(...);
} catch (e) {
    ...
}
```

nor

```
SC.stream(..., function(sound, error));
```

work.

**Test Case** (https://soundcloud.com/klangkarussell/sonnentanz-sun-don-t-shine-2):

```
SC.stream("/tracks/112609088");
```

Related to this question: [SoundCloud: "streamable" inconsistent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30037446/soundcloud-streamable-inconsistent)